# syntax error in shell_exec php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm stumped seems everything is right don't know why it gives an error

```
<?php
    echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n";
    echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Videos/*.* -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -crf 24  /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Videos/Output/"${i%.*}.mp4 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/var/log/ffmpeg.log &");
    echo "Done.\n";
?>
```

and yes this codes runs in terminal

```
for i in *.*; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -crf 24 n/"${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Comment: According to the syntax highlighting, there's a mismatch with your `"` characters.

Comment: What error? You should always provide the error instead of just mentioning you get an error. Your two commands are not the same. In the command in the PHP script you have two inputs but `ffmpeg` will only use one for the output with your current command. Also, the wildcard will expand into one input and multiple outputs potentially overwriting the inputs if you confirm overwrite with `-y` or by pressing the *y* key.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems, but the main thing is that your using double quotes round the string and double quotes round some of the values.  There is also the use of `$i` which PHP will attempt to process as a variable.

```
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -i /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Videos/*.* -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -crf 24  /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Videos/Output/"${i%.*}.mp4 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/var/log/ffmpeg.log &');
```

Using single quotes round the whole string will both stop the problem of quotes in the string, but also stop PHP trying to interpret any fields.

**Update:**

Not sure about using the shell to do this, but you could write something like...

```
$fileList = glob("/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Videos/*.*");
foreach ( $fileList as $file ){
    if ( is_file($file) ){
        //echo shell_exec("echo \"$file\"");
        echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("ffmpeg -i $file -c:v libx264 -crf 24 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Videos/Output/$file.mp4 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/var/log/ffmpeg.log"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I run the php, I just want to run for i in *.*; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -crf 24 n/"${i%.*}.mp4"; done on a php script